# Is RestKit the only framework that has JSON to Objective-C objects mapping?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, json, object-object-mapping

I am looking for a library or framework that does JSON to Objective-C relational object mapping.
i.e. I need to map JSON containing objects, array of objects and dictionaries of objects to my custom objects.

something like:

```
DataObject {
    "user" : {
        "name":"Peter",
        "id":1234
    }
    "place": "UK"
    "job": {
        "title" : "CTO",
        "salary" : 1234567
    }
    "employess": [
        {
            "name":"Carlton",
            "id":1235
        },
        {
            "name":"Hugo",
            "id":12346
        }]
}
```

So there is a DataObject a UserObject and an employees array consisting of UserObjects.
I would like for the mapping from the JSON to my DataObject to happen "automatically", of course meant as I would like to describe the objects and there relations in the Object class and have the mapping done from this, instead of manually mapping each nested object.
(First level native objective-c properties are easily done with setValue:forKey and other KVO methods, but from there on it gets complicated).

I have been testing out RestKit but it seems there is no way to pick and choose which functionality you need from that framework, it is either all of it or none of it, and I do find it does too much for my needs.

Are anyone familiar with a library etc. out there that can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the libs on http://json.org? (I haven't, so I can't tell if they're any good)

Comment: @Black Frog ..I do find it does too much for my needs... sorry about that.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 As far as I can see none of the libraries or frameworks there does object mapping of anything other than Objective-C types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted above isn't valid JSON. If you made it valid JSON what you want to do is impossible without a specific schema, eg.

```
{
    "DataObject": {
        "user": {
            "name": "Peter",
            "id": 1234
        },
        "place": "UK",
        "job": {
            "title": "CTO",
            "salary": 1234567
        }
    }
}
```

Is Dataobject a dictionary or an Object? What about User or Job? What is User is an instance of NSUser and job is an NSDictionary?

On the other hand, if you have a known schema:-

```
[
    {
        "class": "DataObject",
        "properties": {
            "user": {
                "class": "User",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "id": 1234
                }
            },
            "place": "UK",
            "job": {
                "title": "CTO",
                "salary": 1234567
            }
        }
    }
]
```

you don't need a framework as it is trivial to map to your objects yourself once you have valid JSON. Pseudocode:-

```
createWithDict(dict) {
    var newOb = create new(dict["class"]);
    dict.properties.each( val, key ) {
        if(val is dictionary && val.hasproperty("class"))
            val = createWithDict(val)
        newOb[key] = val
    }   
    return newOb;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you could miss out the "class:" property and just see if a Class exists with that name using NSClassFromString(@"DataObject") - a bit dangerous, you could even go one further and inspect the type of the property on the parent Object.

Answer (score 2):

To map JSON to Objective-C objects, I have tried RestKit. I used it a while ago, so my criticisms might not apply anymore.
What I found out: nice idea. Not too complicated to plug-in. If it works, great for you. But if not, or if you need to push it a bit further, good luck to debug.
I regret the time I invested in it.

I am only looking for JSON to Objective-C objects, not the other way around.
I found a link on  SO to [JTObjectMapping](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTObjectMapping) - but can't find the original answer. Seems more lightweight and close to what I was searching, but I did not had the opportunity to try it.

An other similar class: [jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor).

I prefer the approach of this two classes over RestKit, as it only takes care of one job, whereas RestKit tried to handle everything.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I recently enhanced JTObjectMapping's auto mapping feature to include underscores to CamelCases. Say you don't need to configure anything to allow "full_name" to "fullName". Cheers